# how to parse multiple json arrays in android studio

Tags: json, android-studio, gson

I try to build an app to parse one ore more json arrays in android studio when they are available on the server. My code is:

`

```
private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
        String name;
  public DownloadImage(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        private void updateLabel() {
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpRequestParams());
                HttpGet getJson = new HttpGet(SERVER_ADRESS + "/objects.json");
                HttpResponse jsonResponse = client.execute(getJson);
                if (200 == jsonResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()) {
                    InputStream inputStream = jsonResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                    String json = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
                    JsonResult jsonResult = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonResult.class);

                    String label = jsonResult.objects.get(0).label;
                    TextView Result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    Result.setText("Your instrument could be a " + label);}
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
     }
```

The json file is:
`{"file": "image.jpg", "objects": [{"bbox": [257, 59, 544, 799], "label": "spanishguitar", "prob": 0.6061},]}`

In this case it works! But sometimes the json has two "label"-arrays and looks like that:

`{"file": "image.jpg", "objects": [{"bbox": [257, 59, 544, 799], "label": "spanishguitar", "prob": 0.6061}, {"bbox": [247, 65, 546, 794], "label": "cavaquinho", "prob": 0.5541}]}`

My idea was to use if else like this:

```
 if (200 == jsonResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()) {
                    InputStream inputStream = jsonResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                    String json = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
                    JsonResult jsonResult = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonResult.class);
                    String label = jsonResult.objects.get(0).label;
                    String label2 = jsonResult.objects.get(1).label;

                   if (label2 != null){
                       TextView Result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                       Result.setText("Your instrument could be a " + label + " or a " + label2);
                }
                  else {
                       TextView Result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                       Result.setText("Your instrument could be a " + label);
                   }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

The output ("Your instrument could be a spanishguitar or a cavanquinho") is printed when both label and label2 are in the json-file. Is there only one label, there is no output.

Do you have any ideas? Maybe I am totaly wrong?

Comment: Try printing complete json response as well as `label` and `label2` values to console OR inspect these values in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that i first declare a variable that was null and then I set the "if object(1) != null". That was the reason for the nullpointer.
The solution I found is:

```
private void updateLabel() {
                try {
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpRequestParams());
                    HttpGet getJson = new HttpGet(SERVER_ADRESS + "objects.json");
                    HttpResponse jsonResponse = client.execute(getJson);
                    if (200 == jsonResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()) {
                        InputStream inputStream = jsonResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                        String json = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
                        JsonResult jsonResult = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonResult.class);
                        String label = jsonResult.objects.get(0).label;

                       TextView Result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                          Result.setText("Your instrument could be a " + label);


                        if (jsonResult.objects.get(1) != null) {
                            String label2 = jsonResult.objects.get(1).label;
                            if(label2 != null) {
                                Result.setText("Your instrument could be " + label + " or " + label2);
                            }

                             if (jsonResult.objects.get(2) != null) {
                                String label3 = jsonResult.objects.get(2).label;
                                if(label3 != null) {
                                    Result.setText("Your instrument could be " + label + " or " + label2 + " or " + label3);
                                }
                            }
                        }         
                    }}
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }}
```